# Make vuetify app bar items align with <v-container> body content

Tags: vuetify.js

The stock app bar component aligns items hard left, and if using the `v-spacer` component will the push items to the hard right.

[image]

I have tried wrapping the button items with `v-container` inside the `v-app-bar` but it breaks the layout once other components are added.

Ideally, the button on the left would align with `hello` and likewise with the buttons on the right, they should align with the right side of the `v-container` of the body.

I tried wrapping `v-app-bar` with `v-container`:
[image]

This is essentially the layout I want but obviously not with the background colour pushed in, it should fill out the width like in the first image.

Is there a native way to do this or will I need to get creative?

```html
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-app-bar
                color="indigo accent-4"
                dense
                flat
                dark
        >
            <v-btn icon>
                <v-icon>mdi-home-outline</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <v-divider inset vertical></v-divider>

            <v-btn text :key="item.id" v-for="item in items" v-text="item.text"></v-btn>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn text v-text="'Sign In'"></v-btn>
            <v-btn text v-text="'Register'"></v-btn>
        </v-app-bar>
    </v-container>
</template>
```

Similar question but no answers. [Problem with placing v-app-bar content in container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64685095/problem-with-placing-v-app-bar-content-in-container)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a workaround in the interim, not sure how clean it is:

My solution looks like so:

[image]

The colors show the nav bar width adjusted to match the body. The code looks like so:

```html
<template>
    <v-sheet color="red">
        <v-container class="pa-0">
            <v-app-bar
                    dense
                    flat
                    color="blue accent-4"
            >
                <v-btn icon>
                    <v-icon>mdi-home-outline</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
                <v-divider inset vertical></v-divider>

                <v-btn text :key="item.id" v-for="item in quickLinks" v-text="item.text"></v-btn>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn text v-text="'Sign In'"></v-btn>
                <v-btn text v-text="'Register'"></v-btn>
            </v-app-bar>
        </v-container>
    </v-sheet>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want the `v-app-bar` to be fixed to the top of the page, I solved this by wrapping a `v-app-bar` inside a `v-container` inside another `v-app-bar`:

```html
<template>
  <v-app-bar app fixed dense color="grey lighten-4" elevation="1">
    <v-container>
      <v-app-bar dense elevation="0">
        <v-app-bar-title nuxt href="/">
          My Title
        </v-app-bar-title>
      </v-app-bar>
    </v-container>
  </v-app-bar>
</template>
```